# Flutter provider automatically scroll to bottom on list item add

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using flutter provider package for state management. My home screen is listening for child addition inside a ListView. Everything is fine. But I am not able to scroll the list view to the bottom when a new item has been added from the ChangeNotifier.

I am using the below code to scroll to bottom, it works when done manually. But as you can see change is happening from the provider model and list view is somewhere else. How do I scroll to bottom on child addition to ListView?

```
final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  void _scrollDown() {
    _controller.animateTo(
      _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }
```

then inside ListView

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: faqModel.getChatItems(),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: where do you call `_scrollDown` method?  
and where do you add a list view item?

Comment: yeah that's the problem. I can not call _scrollDown as item is added from the provider model. _scrollDown resides in the view. How do I listen for the change in the model?

Comment: so when is a child added to your list inside the provider model?